# Icon for partialy visible

Tags: icons

I have a collapsible hierarchical list of items. The child items can be made invisible, when this happens a 'hidden' icon is displayed next to the item in the list (shown with an @ in my example)

```
|-@ parent 1                        <-partially hidden
|    |- @ Child 1                   <-hidden
|    |- @ Child 2                   <-hidden
|    |- Child 3
|- parent 2
```

I would like an icon on the parent to show whether it's children are shown or hidden. It is easy to come up with icons for all hidden or all visible but I cannot think of a way of showing partially hidden

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common pattern, simply use `+` and `-` signs. As you can see in the image below, a `+` sign denotes there's more content, a `-` sign denotes that you can hide those visible items.

[image]

## However...

If you want to convey that SOME files are hidden, you can use another common pattern: **File select.** See image below:

[image]

In this case, when some files are selected while other files aren't, the accepted pattern is to **show a square in the select box**. While you don't have a select box, you can easily use the same approach and most users will understand it. Of course, you must test it!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I wasn't clear in my question, when the child items are made invisible this isn't refferring to collapsing them in the list but to a state elsewhere in the application on a canvas. The second suggestion is closer but I would ideally like a more explicit reference to visibility e.g. with an eye

Answer (score -1):

This is the icon I know best for hidden items:

[image]

https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/470389/hidden <-- SVG

You can use it like so:

[image: parent child hierarchy]

Now, the design was quickly thrown together, forgive me :D. But that's a simple use of it.

Comment: Do you know of a similar icon for partially hidden

Comment: @partialhiddenicon this is a tough one. You could do the eye but partially closed. You might have to make that yourself. You could also try a half eye open half closed. You could try using colour as well to show that not all items are hidden, grey means all items are hidden and black would mean some items are hidden.